# Set Users' passwords

Tags: users, password

When you create a new user in the craft backend CMS, it used to be possible to set (and change for existing users) the password.  It appears recently (last 6 months+) that this feature has been removed, is there a simple way to re-instate this feature or is the only way to set the password the password re-set url feature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For security reasons, this was changed in [Craft 2.3...](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2615)

> Admins are no longer allowed to change other users’ passwords.

But savvy admins can still pull it off... Simply click the gear icon in the right sidebar, and select "Copy password reset URL". Then, instead of sending that URL to the user, just use it yourself.

[image]