# Register front end member from admin area with password

Tags: users, registration, password

I'm not certain if this is possible but what we want to do is the following:

Have an admin register a new user in the admin, including a password for them so that they can pass along these credentials along via offline channels - and then that user will log into a front end client area.

I don't think it's possible to add a password - which surprises me in terms of use-cases needing to manage new users subscriptions by someone else and wanting disseminate specific credentials.

Is this possible?

If not, is it possible to:

1. Register the new member in the admin (without a password)
2. Have a custom Activate Account email confirmation go to them to finish their account signup, prompting them to go to:
3. A page where they can complete this, adding their new password and then logging them into their client account area

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet here is going to be to create a plugin.

One way that this could work would be to set up a plugin that defines a [record](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/records) for the front-end users, and then create one or more Control Panel pages for your Administrator to handle these records. Because the records can be defined any way you'd like, they can exist separately from Craft's baked-in User system.

This may actually be preferable in your case, since (if I'm understanding correctly) it sounds like you'd like to manage users logging into a separate frontend area, not the Craft admin Control Panel.

Regarding the Admin ability to manage User's passwords from the Control Panel, this feature was removed in build 2.3.2615. However, [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10588/set-users-passwords/10591#10591) does offer a way around this.

Comment: Thanks Sam. We'll look at the records more but are you suggesting then that the act of the Admin creating that user would happen outside of the baked-in User section also via our plugin? (And your understanding regarding a front-end client area only is correct)

Comment: That's correct - Plugins can include Control Panel page templates, and so the idea would simply to create one to to along with your plugin. The front-end user management would then still happen within the control panel, but outside of  / separately from Craft's users.

You could then think of your Plugin as the managing tool for your front-end client users, and the baked-in Craft User's area as the managing tool for your developers or administrators. Hope that helps!

Comment: Yep - that does. Thanks Sam - much appreciated.

Comment: No problem, glad to hear it!